# Why do I get a 403 error when visiting /javascript on my website?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

I was just playing around with a small web application I wrote today, [wetagg.in](http://wetagg.in/).

When I visit the site with a path, like http://wetagg.in/unix, it will take `unix` as input and render content accordingly.

This is all great, until I visit http://wetagg.in/javascript and get a 403 error. Naturally, I check my logs and they say:

> `[Wed Jul 09 00:27:43 2014] [error] [client ...] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /usr/share/javascript/`

Why would the request be interpreted as an access to `/usr/share/javascript`?

The directory exists, but the problem is not reproducible with other folders in `/usr/share`, like with http://wetagg.in/python

In case it isn't obvious, I have *not* set up any rewrite rules in this regard for the virtual host myself and this behavior actually affects all websites hosted on the server.

The virtual host configuration can be inspected as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/oliversalzburg/c2f836ffb2912697d224). But, as I said, the problem affects all sites hosted on the server. The application itself is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/tag.this).

Comment: This obviously can't be answered without seeing your virtual host configuration and the code of your application. The most likely explanation is a bug in your code.

Comment: @Gilles https://github.com/oliversalzburg/tag.this

Comment: Please edit your question so that it includes all the relevant information. As you well know, we don't want questions that depends on external content that may change or go away at any time.

Comment: @Gilles Understood. I assumed this issue is caused by the default configuration of the packages involved.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, a default alias for `/javascript` is created through `/etc/apache2/conf.d/javascript-common.conf`

See [Cannot access javascript folder](https://serverfault.com/questions/274254/cannot-access-javascript-folder) for reference.